# Results of XML parsing start from the last &amp; found in the

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xml-parsing, youtube-api, nsxmlparser

I'm currently using the Youtube API and getting results from the channel. However when I try to get the description it always stops at the last `&amp;` and I only get a part of the description.

Here's the website where I'm getting the XML information from 
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/smosh/uploads?max-results=1

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"content"])
    {
        currentFeed.description = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"entry"])
    {
        [self.feeds addObject:currentFeed];
        currentFeed = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

The content is getting the description from the video.

However I only get these results

```
Wardrobe: Paula Barkley Asst. Editor: Justin Dailey | Color: Pretty Moving Pictures BTS: Phil Mohr | Key PA: Brad Westerbeck

------------------------------------ Hey it's our very own website: http://smosh.com Oh and our Facebook page: http://facebook.com/smosh Want to know when we're filming and/or pooping? Now you can:http://twitter.com/smosh Guess we should have a Google+ Page, too: http://google.com/+smosh
```

When this is the whole description:

```
Bloopers &amp; ALTERNATE SCENES: http://smo.sh/FriendsXTRAS DOWNLOAD OUR NEW GAME: http://smo.sh/HeadEsploder

Ian and Anthony need some new friends.

Cast: Anthony as Himself Ian as Himself Ryan Todd as Stevie Ryan Cicak and Robert Haley as the New Neighbors

Written by: Anthony Padilla, Ian Hecox, &amp; Ryan Finnerty Produced &amp; Directed by: Anthony Padilla, Ian Hecox, &amp; Ryan Todd Edited by: Anthony Padilla &amp; Michael Barryte Post Supervision by: Ian Hecox &amp; Ryan Finnerty

AD: Frank Cosgriff | DP: John Alexander Jimenez Asst. Camera: Shawna Smith | Sound Mixer: Palmer Taylor Gaffer: Kerry Sweeney | Grips: Jon Hooker &amp; Lee Eisenhower Production Design: Patrick Egan | MUA &amp; Wardrobe: Paula Barkley Asst. Editor: Justin Dailey | Color: Pretty Moving Pictures BTS: Phil Mohr | Key PA: Brad Westerbeck

------------------------------------  Hey it's our very own website: http://smosh.com Oh and our Facebook page: >http://facebook.com/smosh Want to know when we're filming and/or pooping? Now you can:http://twitter.com/smosh Guess we should have a Google+ Page, too: http://google.com/+smosh
```

[Here's my whole class file](http://pastebin.com/5KUsRCfV)

Comment: What are you doing in `parser:didStartElement:...` and `parser:foundCharacters:`?

Comment: Here's my whole class http://pastebin.com/5KUsRCfV , If you could help me I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: @GretarAgnarsson While I answer your question below, an unrelated observation. You use a cast in `foundCharacters` to assign a `NSString` object to a `NSMutableString *` variable. Never cast an immutable object into a mutable variable; in the future, use the `mutableCopy` method instead. A cast of an immutable string to a mutable one doesn't "convert" it for you, but rather just suppressed an important compiler error. You can get into a world of hurt if you use that pattern. Turns out, you don't need that code at all, so it's a moot point, but a friendly warning about a dangerous practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that  `foundCharacters` returns the entire value for an element in a single call. This is not a valid assumption (especially for long values). This is why you're only seeing the end of the `content` tag, because the rest of the value was returned in prior calls to `foundCharacters`, but you discarded that on each subsequent call to `foundCharacters`.

For a long value, the sequence of events is (a) a call to `didStartElement`; (b) multiple calls to `foundCharacters` until the whole value is returned; and finally (c) a call to `didEndElement`.

So:

1. Have `didStartElement` initialize `currentNodeContent` if it encounters either the `title` and `content` element names:

   ```
   currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   ```
2. Then, `foundCharacters` should just append the `string` to `currentNodeContent`:

   ```
   [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
   ```

   NB: Make sure it does *not* trim the string (if you want to trim, do that in `didEndElement`, not in `foundCharacters`).
3. Have `didEndElement` save the `currentNodeContent` if the element name is `title` or `content` and it should also then set `currentNodeContent` to `nil`.

Comment: Hmm I tried this and the content returned as a (null), Could you try to edit my code ? pastebin.com/5KUsRCfV  Any help is greatly appreciated, I need to get this finished asap.

Comment: @GretarAgnarsson I didn't see any of your attempt to integrate my above comments, but I would expected it to be something like http://pastebin.com/kti2gAEf

Comment: @GretarAgnarsson I would also seriously discourage you from using global variables like that. No compelling need for it here and no good can come of this (e.g. if you did any simultaneous background parsing, your objects would collide with each other). Use class instance variables, such as http://pastebin.com/SdDXn9vT.

Comment: Wow Rob, thank you so much for all this information. I really appreciate your help!! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but could you take a look at this ? This started happening after I started using V2 API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532339/quick-fix-with-xml