# Quick fix with XML?

Tags: objective-c, xml, youtube-api

I'm currently using the YouTube API V2 and I'm getting incorrect data while gathering the description of the video.

[This is the link where I'm getting the XML information from.](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gudjondaniel/uploads?v=2&max-results=1)

This is the string I'm suppose to be getting

> Can we hit 5000 Likes for all the great goals? :)
>   http://www.facebook.com/GudjonDanielYT
>   https://twitter.com/GudjonDaniel

but I get this one

> GudjonDanielhttp://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GudjonDanielkM0YirXKa4Lb7MsgqHWiMwEntertainmentgudjondanielCan
>   we hit 5000 Likes for all the great goals? :)
>   http://www.facebook.com/GudjonDanielYT
>   https://twitter.com/GudjonDaniel

My code, it's in the `media:description`

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementname isEqualToString:@"content"])
    {
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"entry"])
    {
        currentFeed = [ChanelFeeds alloc];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"yt:duration"])
    {
        currentFeed.duration = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"seconds"];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"yt:statistics"])
    {
        currentFeed.views = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"viewCount"];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"gd:rating"])
    {
        currentFeed.rating = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"average"];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:player"])
    {
        currentFeed.streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"] && !currentFeed.thumbnailURL)
    {
        currentFeed.thumbnailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        currentFeed.title = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"media:description"])
    {
        currentFeed.description = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"entry"])
    {
        [self.feeds addObject:currentFeed];
        currentFeed = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element names you're looking for in `didStartElement` (which initializes `currentNodeContent`) don't match the element names that you're using to save and reset the `currentNodeContent` in your `didEndElement` method.

Thus, your lines that say:

```
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementname isEqualToString:@"content"])
{
    currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```

Probably should say:

```
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementname isEqualToString:@"media:description"])
{
    currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
```